# Regex to capture #Facilitator:"Full Name <mail@mail.domain>" tags

Tags: java, python, php, regex, bash

**Please help with the regex, the language can be any. I'll later translate it to python.**

I'm trying to build a regex to capture the tag below:

```
#Facilitator:"Full Name <mail@mail.domain>"
```

- Full name can be with accents like José, Pâmela, or any available in the ASCII table.
- Full name can have 1, 2 or n family names. Could have or not a '(comapny name)' at the end of the name: like `#Facilitator:"Name1 Name2 Name3 (Company Inc) <mail@domain>"`
- The tag can appear 0, 1 or n times in strings.
- The tag can appear in any place of the string.

So far trying like this (python) but no success:

```
import re

notes = 'Verbal confirmation #Facilitator:"Fernas P. Loyola (YARDA LTDA) <ope@yahoo.com>"from ATUX with Melanie. Waiting for scheduling#Facilitator:"Fernandes <v-rrlo@stttr.de>" #Facilitator:"Pablito Ferdinandes <papa@gmail.com>"'

facilitator_regex = '^.*((#Facilitator:".*"){1,}).*$'
regex_replace = '\\1'

print(re.sub(facilitator_regex, regex_replace, notes))
```

**The output i expect is a list of 0, 1 or more #tags separated by a space.**

Any help on any language? I need help mostly with the regex itself. thanks so much.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: the tags separated by space!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the facilitators using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20findall#re.findall) with this regex:

```
'#Facilitator:"[^"]*"'
```

e.g.

```
facilitator_regex = '#Facilitator:"[^"]*"'
facilitators = re.findall(facilitator_regex, notes)
```

For your sample data this gives

```
[
 '#Facilitator:"Fernas P. Loyola (YARDA LTDA) <ope@yahoo.com>"',
 '#Facilitator:"Fernandes <v-rrlo@stttr.de>"',
 '#Facilitator:"Pablito Ferdinandes <papa@gmail.com>"'
]
```

You could then use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join) to make a space-separated list:

```
print(' '.join(facilitators))
```

Output:

```
#Facilitator:"Fernas P. Loyola (YARDA LTDA) <ope@yahoo.com>" #Facilitator:"Fernandes <v-rrlo@stttr.de>" #Facilitator:"Pablito Ferdinandes <papa@gmail.com>"
```

Comment: amazing. that solved the problem. I'm curious to know if there's any regex that would do the job without the use of re.findall. In my old days i used to do such things with sed wich would be similar to do it using re.sub and doing a regex a bit more complex. thank you for your help.

Comment: @Pabluez it can be done but requires a significantly more complex (and slower to process) regex: https://rextester.com/DHGB68622